# Python : I am trying to replace a string 'redlight' with 'greenlight' within a list

Tags: python, string, replace

I am attempting to use the string replace function, but cannot execute. The code I have so far is:

```
def replace_rf(f):
    for line in f:
        if 'redflag' in line:
            line.replace('redflag', 'greenflag')
            all_green_flags.append(line)
            print(line, '\n')

with open('access.log', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

If you can provide some guidance I would be greatful.

Comment: You need to either assign `line.replace` back to `line` or just append `line.replace(...)` directly. `str.replace` is not an in-place operation.

Comment: Can you post few sample lines of your input file and your desired output file?

Comment: he's saying you'll need to reassign the variable `line` like so: `line = line.replace('redflag', 'greenflag')`. because the `.replace` method does not modify the variable in place.